# Is it possible to reference a variable before defining it?

Tags: php

A very simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
$quote = "Currently showing number $i";

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
echo $quote;
}
```

Where the `$i` from `$quote` is constantly updated with the new value.

Again this is a simplified example. I realize it could be reordered to accomplish the same thing or a `str_replace()` used, but for the real code it could not be accomplished.

Comment: maybe you can combine with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)/[`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) which would have a placeholder that you can dynamically assign the value of `$i` to:

```
$quote = "Currently showing number %u";

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    printf($quote, $i);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bPltZ)

Comment: That does work, but is there something similar to that using names rather than regular expressions? So instead of $i I could use %u, I could use %thisNumber or something similar?

Comment: That isn't a regular expression. It's a placeholder. This in the exact functionally you're looking for. If you want to be able to use a custom placeholder name you'll have to use str_replace or a regular expression.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer to the question, but it doesn't particularly do what I was hoping. But it does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like:

```
$quote = "Currently showing number ";

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
echo $quote.$i;
}
```

Comment: I think you are taking their simplified example too literally

Comment: Just working with what I get.  I can't see why you wouldn't provide the details needed in the question. but people are odd. https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer

```
<?php

$quote = 'Currently showing number $i';
$pattern = '/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $quote, $matches);

for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $valName) {
        if (isset(${$valName})) {
            $result = str_replace($matches[0][$index], ${$valName}, $quote);
        }
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: "Here is your answer" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)